# " end=' ' " problem(How to keep the line from changing?)

Tags: python

I want to print out two 'print' sentences in one line, what should I do?
(I want to print that sentence only once.)

```
sentence = input("Enter a text.:")
for i in range(len(sentence)-1,-1,-1):
    print("Received string :",sentence,"Inverse order of inputted string")
    print(sentence[i],end='')
```

Comment: Related: [Reverse a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931092/reverse-a-string-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you wish for:

```
sentence = input("Enter a text:")
print(f"Received string: {sentence}\nInverse order of inputted string: {sentence[::-1]}")
```

with a for loop:

```
sentence = input("Enter a text:")
print(f"Received string:\n{sentence}","\nInverse order of inputted string:")
for i in range(len(sentence)-1,-1,-1):
  print(sentence[i],end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is correct. The problem is that you're printing a "received string" message at each step of your reversal. Simply move that line out of your for loop and you're good!

```py
print("Received string :",sentence,"Inverse order of inputted string")
for i in range(len(sentence)-1,-1,-1):
  print(sentence[i],end='')
```